# EFCore Scaffold : generate contexts inheriting from subclasses of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffold

I am using EF Core scaffold to generate my contexts and model classes.

For each DB, Scaffold generates a context class that inherits from DbContext class, which is quite logical.

Now, I would like to mutualize some features for all my DbContext classes into a MyDbContextBase, inheriting from DbContext.
And I would like Scaffold to generate the DB context classes inheriting from this MyDbContextBase, instead of inheriting from Dbcontext.
Is that possible?

I did not see any options that would help me to do it.
And I clearly do not want to update the Scaffold generated class manually everytime that I regenerate the model classes via Scaffold to change the base class from DbContext to MyDbContextBase.

Comment: Why do you want this? What does `MyDbContextBase` do? Quite often people try to create base contexts for very wrong reasons, like trying to "fix" things that aren't broken. Even if the reasons are correct, there's no need to inherit from a custom base class to customize generated classes. All classes are `partial` which means you can add extra code in another partial class file. These files will be preserved even if you regenerate the DbContext files

Comment: In EF Core 7 you can use [custom templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to scaffold both DbContexts and entities the way you want.

Comment: Are you trying to add auditing by overriding `SaveChanges`? Or configure a common set of [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) for all DbContexts? Inheritance is the most cumbersome way to do this. First, you can add interceptors even for SaveChanges. Second, adding auditing/interceptors in the base class forces *all* DbContexts to use them, whether they need them or not. In the interceptors docs, inheritance is reversed. In `ExampleContext : BlogsContext`, the new context adds interceptors to an existing "plain" DbContext

Comment: If you use AddDbContext you are able to customize interceptors inside `AddDbContext` based on configuration settings or flags without affecting the rest of the application. You'll be able to switch auditing on and off as needed, or test your DbContexts without having to add mock audit targets

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
You figured it out correctly. We want this because we want to override SaveChanges() in the partial class.
In our case, we want to check conditions and possibly return an exception if they are not met. 
All my DbContext want the same override, so it would make sense to me to use inheritance.
And if one of the DbContext eventually does not need this override, I will just not make it inherit from MyDbContextBase.

Comment: *Why* do you want to override SaveChanges though? That's the assumed solution to the problem. It doesn't mean it's correct. You don't need inheritance if you can add an `ISaveChangesInterceptor` in your `AddDbContext` for example. That's just an `AddInterceptors` call before or after the `UseSqlServer` or `UseMySql` call. What's the actual problem you want to solve by overriding `SaveChanges` ?

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? `ISaveChangesInterceptor` is available since EF Core 5. Custom DbContext templates were added in EF Core 7. To use custom templates in previous versions you need tools like eg [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering)

Comment: I certainly agree that it might not be the best solution.
We overrided Savechanges because we did not know about the interceptors. :)
Let me review how it works, and if it would solve our issues in a better way, pros and cons.
Thx a lot for this first suggestion.

Comment: At this stage we use EF Core 6. we will move to 7 in a couple months.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#customize-code-using-handlebars) for custom generation. It has many features that are still not available in the scaffolding tools. EF Core's scaffolding command isn't meant to be a full featured code generator . And T4 ... everyone has ... thoughts... about T4 templates.

Comment: I like the Interceptors well enough. Very smart tool indeed!
It definitely looks appropriate to my problem. Though, from a team point of view, I find this solution trickier to deal with.
Some of our devs will miss that some of the DbContext code is executed by the Interceptor.
So I think I will rather suggest my team to wait for EF 7 migration and deal with the templates, or do it by now with Power Tools as per your suggestion.